# How to clear the eclipse .project files from maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

After I import my maven project to eclipse, it created eclipse project files in my maven project. How do I clear them out?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you don't want eclipse project files why are you using it ? This file is compulsory to work with eclipse.

Comment: if I dont clean the project files, how to I hand it over to someone else? If they dont use eclipse would they be appreciate all those extra files unrelated to the project?

Comment: Are you using a version control system?

Answer (score 0):

After your comment "if I dont clean the project files, how to I hand it over to someone else? If they dont use eclipse would they be appreciate all those extra files unrelated to the project?" I have understood your need.

The best way to achieve it is to use a version control system (VCS) like git, svn etc. and add inside your project tree a special file call .[VCSofYourChoice]ignore. For example for git this file would be .gitignore for svn it would be .svnignore.

Once you created this file you add rules to exclude files or directories you don't want to share on your version control system of your choice. To find the syntax to use google it with keywords ".[VCSofYourChoice]ignore syntax".

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse and eventually every IDE create specific files, in order to save project structure and other internals. Some of them prompt you to select in which folder you want to save these files, for example IntelliJ, but I am sure eclipse as well. So you every time you use and IDE and you import a project, some files are going to be generated. The cleanest way is to 1) select to save them in a folder not related with the actual project, and as it already suggested do not commit them and add them in an ignore list, on your VCS of choice (e.g git)